# How can I mount ext3 with restricted permissions, like setting uid, gid and umask?

Tags: linux, mount, ext3, umask

I want to mount an ext3 filesystem on a device with `uid`, `gid`, `umask` options set. When I use these options during `mount`, I get an error.

Below is the command I am using to mount:

```
mount -t ext3 -o uid=1001, gid=1001, umask=0066 /dev/mapper/mdev5 /dir
```

Is there any alternate to do so using mount?

Comment: Why do you think `umask` is an option you can set with `ext3` filesystems?

Comment: Check the allowable mount options for ext3 in your mount man page. As far as I'm aware, `umask` is not available for `ext3`, and from a brief reading I'm not sure `uid` and `gid` are either.

Answer (score 0):

Read [manpage for mount](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) command. It says,

> `-o, --options opts Options are specified with a -o flag followed by a comma separated string of options`

so, your command should be,

mount -t ext3 -ouid=1001,gid=1001,umask=0066 /dev/mapper/mdev5 /dir

(without space between options)

Comment: ext3 does not have an uid option, at least not on ubuntu 12 and older.